# FFMPEG movie not compatible with QuickTime with yuv420p tag

Tags: quicktime

I've recently downloaded and started using ffmpeg to convert a series of images to a .mp4 movie. It won't open in QuickTime, saying that the file is incompatible. In other threads I've seen that this is fixed with `-pix_fmt yuv420p`, but that doesn't fix the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the entire command:

```
$ ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -pix_fmt yuv420p -tag:v hvc1 -i "*.png" test.mp4
```

And here's the resultant error message when trying to open test.mp4 with QuickTime:
[image: QuickTime Error]

Comment: google found this - https://superuser.com/questions/820134/why-cant-quicktime-play-a-movie-file-encoded-by-ffmpeg [I've no real idea if it would help;)

Comment: What version of macOS are you using?